# Using wont work but direct reference will

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reference, using

I am attempting to reference another class in another project in the same solution.

I can use direct references like this:

[image]

However I would like to just use a reference like this

`using ClearspanHelperLibrary.DimensionConverters;`

Which does not cause an error but it doesnt allow me to use my type without any prefix

However it will not seem to recognize the using when i put it at the top of the file.

I am certain I have it referenced in my project.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the colorization of the text in the image that you posted, it looks like DimensionCovnerters is a type, not a namespace. Maybe `ArchitecturalDimensionStyles` is an inner class of `DimensionConverters`.

Try:

```
using ClearspanHelperLibrary;
...
DimensionConverters.ArchitecturalDimensionStyles myVar;
```

Comment: you are right. is there any way I can do the same type of thing that I do with namespaces with classes, so I dont have to type `DimensionConverters.` each time?

Comment: could jth41 use the `using ArchitecturalDimensionStyles = DimensionConverters.ArchitecturalDimensionStyles` in the namespace to make the code easier to write

Comment: I shouldnt have to do that. Types from referenced classes should be usable with just a regular using.

Comment: @jth41 - not if they are defined within another class

Answer (score 0):

This may be case like in `System.configuration`. You have to explicitly add the reference in your project before you can reference it in code.